# Mystery water leak

Tags: plumbing

Got a letter from water dept that I was using 1300 gal a day and there might be something wrong. Amazingly the city has a site that shows my daily use graphically.

About August 25th it shot up to over 5000 gal a day and then, almost monotonically, it decreased day by day for a month to about 500 gal a day then dropped back to normal. It has stayed that way for three weeks.

Only evidence of leaked water is a patch of very damp very soft earth at a spot in the backyard close to the house. Single story built 1950s on a slab with 2016 addition. No pool. Copper pipes in attic so some repiping has been done.

Using a pressure meter I can see that the house does not hold pressure for even 5 seconds.

So if it doesn’t hold pressure why isn’t it currently leaking and how does a huge leak fix itself at all, let alone gradually?

Three plumbers have looked at it. One says they listened to water flows and narrowed down the bad segment (to a location in the addition). Another with the same equipment doesn’t hear anything. One says repiping is needed one says it’s been repiped. Moved here 6 years ago.

One plumper dug down two feet at the damp spot to see if water would run in from somewhere but just found more damp earth. Said that indicated leak was not immediately adjacent. Another plumber said water finds its way by the path of least resistance and the leak could be fairly distant.

The meter at the street moves very slowly with nothing running.

[image]

Comment: Leak should be very close to the very damp soft earth.  Leak probably caused a hole in the dirt at first and then caved in blocking most of the leak.  Dig down at damp spot and will have a good chance of finding the leak.

Comment: "normal" was/is probably "leaking, but not that badly" if it's "returned to normal" but is not holding pressure. Dig in the yard where it was wet. carefully. After calling dig-safe or equivalent service to mark all utilities that might also be underground before you dig.

Comment: does the meter spin with all your faucets shut off?  Probably a little LED progress bar if it's an electronic meter.

Comment: One plumper dug down two feet to see if water would run in from somewhere but just found more damp earth. Another plumber said water finds its way by the path of least resistance and the leak could be fairly distant. The meter moves very slowly with nothing running.

Comment: If the meter shows flow with everything off, something's flowing somewhere. Might be a leak in the lateral, might be a slightly stuck-open irrigation valve. I had both this summer. Keep digging...so to speak.

Comment: Follow the water LOL.   Or put it another way, where could a leak *possibly* occur that would NOT also result in water damage, staining and mold?  Like, a flapper or inlet valve leak in the toilet would send the water down the bowl.  Or a hose left hooked up with the faucet on 24x7 might leak outside. Or a sprinkler control valve might not close all the way.

Comment: Your water meter is at the curb/street or at the house? So the water meter moving with "nothing on" is indicating a leak "that could only be inside the house" (if the meter is at the house) or a possible leak that could be "on the line feeding the house" (if at curb)? Please clarify

Comment: At the curb. None of the speculation relates to 5000 gal in a day going down by itself over 30 days. An irrigation valve stuck on or hose turned on would leave a bunch of water somewhere. The only irrigation near the one soaked spot shares a drip line with other very dry areas. And the house does not hold pressure so that rules out some possible causes.

Comment: It's possible, but unlikely, that the meter is faulty. I badgered the City to come out and turn off the City's valve on the input side of the meter, to confirm (in my case) that -0- water flow resulted in a -0- meter reading. It did. While my house's case didn't show a 5000 gallon flow, a careful inspection of the entire property failed to reveal any leakage or soft spots; the land here has both voids and some underground waterflow; the plumber wasn't surprised that no seep was found. Replacing the lateral and cleaning the two irrigation valves reduced the flow at the meter to -0-.